# regarding Windows phone gap application

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I have this function 
    `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { frequency: 1000 })`
     in my application . I have implemented code for `onSuccess` and `onError`methods(parameters) .

Here ever thing is working except `{frequency:3000}` parameter . My code shows longitude and latitude on emulator for `onSuccess` method. For failure, `onError` on emulator. 
But here `{frequency:3000}` is not working. I used `maximumAge:2000` instead of frequency also.
Moto of my application is updating information on a server every 30 seconds. But `frequency` and `maximumAge` are not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Device Properties Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
  //
 function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
  function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           +  position.coords.latitude                   
   + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude                   + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude                    + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy                       + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading                        + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                             + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)                        + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
 function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
 }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

And for example, you can also add something like:

> setTimeout("navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);", 3000);

at the end of your 'OnSuccess' method to automatically refresh your geoloc data every 3s.